# Efficiency while iterating dates in PHP

Tags: php, performance

The purpose of this application is to schedule a large number of machines in a shop in the most efficient way possible.  The process is recursive, assembling schedules and measuring efficiencies. This works, but takes literally days to run.  A significant time drain is the code block below:

```
foreach($machines AS $machine) {
# To begin, we analyze the schedule thus far to get this machine's existing schedule.
    $machSched = array();
    foreach($schedule AS $booking) {
        if($booking['mach']==$machine && strtotime($booking['end']) > date('U')) {
            $machSched[] = $booking;
        }
    }
    # We seek the next time the machine can be booked.  We begin by sorting its current bookings.
    aasort($machSched, 'start');
    # Now we construct the list of available times
    $lastEnd = date('U');
    $freeTimes=array();
    foreach($machSched AS $booking) {
        if(strtotime($booking['start']) > $lastEnd) $freeTimes[] = array('start' => $lastEnd, 'end' => strtotime($booking['start']));
        $lastEnd = strtotime($booking['end']);
    }
    $freeTimes[] = array('start' => $lastEnd, 'end' => strtotime('2030-12-31'));
    # Now we go through each available timeslot to see what we can book.
    foreach($freeTimes AS $slot) {
                   // Scheduling stuff here...
    }
}
```

This block iterates through the existing scheduled times for each machine, sorts them, and creates an array of the "free slots" (times between existing scheduled items.  I've optimized and optimized this program, but I can't seem to come up with a better way to do this one little piece.  Note that aasort is a function to sort an array of associative arrays by a key in the associative arrays.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

If you know the format of how the dates are stored, you should probably use [strptime](http://php.net/strptime) instead of [strtotime](http://php.net/strtotime). Using strtotime means that every call must independently figure out how the date is formatted, so you have to account for that diagnosis in every single loop. It can be a significant difference.

My simple benchmarks show that `time()` is roughly an order of magnitude faster than `date('U')`, and that `strptime()` is 5x faster than `strtotime()`.

Comment: Thanks! With this, I was able to shave 2 seconds per iteration, and brought the total execution time to well under a day.  Obviously still a long way to go, but a definite improvement.

Comment: @user1412922: You're welcome. Once you use effective function choices and cache everything you can, then the only thing you can do is to write it in a compiled language (or run it in parallel somehow).

Answer (score 2):

You do a lot do time conversion ( date() and strftotime() ), but you can avoid all this work using time() and settings inside $booking['start'] and $booking['end'] a simple number.

ADD

Of course you can cache ALL "constant" values in temporary vars: date('U'), strtotime('2030-12-31')).

Comment: Caching these constants did prove to be quite valuable. I think I was spending too much time trying to find a more efficient overall algorithm and not enough time making the one I had faster.

Comment: I can only image what **aasort($machSched, 'start')** does, but if start is unique per $machine you can $machSched[$start] = $booking; and use ksort